# Why doesn't fillRect command allow to create a hit region while a combination of rect and fill does?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics, html5-canvas

I have stumbled upon this issue while working with `CanvasRenderingContext2D.addHitRegion()` and I am trying to undestand whether it's an expected behaviour and, if yes, what is the reasoning behind this.

Here is my working **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/williwaw/33a1mtp6/3/)** where I created a canvas with hit regions and can display the id of clicked region.

Here is how I added hit regions:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, i, canvasWidth, itemHeight);
ctx.fill();
ctx.addHitRegion({'id': count, 'cursor': 'pointer'});
```

And here is the same example with only one small change (*and that's how I tried to do this initially - why use 2 commands when I can use one to do the same?*)

```
ctx.fillRect(0, i, canvasWidth, itemHeight);
ctx.addHitRegion({'id': count, 'cursor': 'pointer'});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work, as shown in this **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/williwaw/5j5s6433/1/)**

The console displays the following error:

> Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'addHitRegion' on
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The specified path has no pixels.

So it seems like in order to create hit region, you cannot use `fillRect` command - and I can't find any explanation to this behaviour.

Will be glad to hear any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fillRect` is one of the direct commands of the `Context2D` : it creates a path 'behind the scene' and fills it instantly.
Meaning it doesn't build a path like rect does, when the hit region requires a path.
Notice that you don't need to fill it, so do it only if you need to.

As a side remark, the browser support for hit region is not that good, as you can see here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/addHitRegion, it is still experimental, so check this out if you want/require a wide support.

As @MarkE quoted, a safe way to implement hit regions is to handle the mouse by yourself (`getBoundingClientRect` is your friend !), your path collection, and to check the coordinates using `isPointInPath`.
Mind, again, that `isPointInPath` expects a path, so it won't work for direct commands (fillXXX / strokeXXX / ImageData stuff).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that there are indirect and direct commands of the Context2D! Now I realize that rect creates a path and fillRect doesn't. Hope this post will save someone's time.

Comment: Upvote for a good explanation of fillRect vs path commands. You might mention that `isPointInPath` can be used as a "poor mans" addHitRegion and `isPointInPath` is well supported.